# Converting a .wxp (Exp document file) in .doc or .odt

Tags: ms-word, libreoffice, scientific-notation, .doc

I'm stuck in trying to open an old paper written in EXP, a word processor for the creation of scientific documents.

Apparently, the file is not readable with word processors in Windows and/or Linux (Ubuntu).

From the website it is possible to download the viewer:
http://www.expswp.com/index.htm
But I would need to convert it in an editable format, as for example .doc or .odt.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Have you thought about printing to file(choose to file instead of printer)? In firefox this is a pdf file and it can be opened in libreoffice. All the best

Comment: Bit of a tricky one this. You can either try the above or you can use Adobe and make reference to this page in relation to the Fonts. I did download the pdf's in libreoffice from this page http://www.expswp.com/support/FAQ/faq00007.htm What I got was a font issue. Saying that i was able to edit the document. All the best